# Как объяснить влияние зависимых слов на орфографию причастий и прилагательных?

Tags: частица-не, прилагательные, причастия, нн

Вот простые примеры:

1) Переход **прилагательного в причастие** при наличии зависимых слов:

*Крашеные волосы, крашенные в разный цвет волосы, но: явно крашеные волосы.*

2) Написание **НЕ с причастиями**:

*Непроверенный текст, еще не проверенный текст; незамерзающая река, не замерзающая зимой река.*

Правила, по которым делается выбор формы написания НЕ или выбор Н/НН **выглядят формальными, но как объяснить их смысл?** Именно эти правила хотели реформировать в 2001 году, чтобы упростить орфографию, но пока оставили их без изменений. Надо ли нам сохранять их?

Так почему же зависимые слова переводят качественный признак в признак по действию? Почему они влияют на написание НЕ именно с причастиями, но не с прилагательными?

И можно ли вообще дать на эти вопросы **простой, короткий и ясный** ответ?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос-то хороший... Только поставлен он не совсем корректно.
Зависимые слова на орфографию причастий и прилагательных не влияют.

В частности, причастия, если это именно причастия, пишутся с удвоенным Н и с зависимыми словами и без них. Равно как и прилагательное в соответствующих случаях не изменяют написания при наличии зависимых слов (в тех, разумеется, случаях, когда такая конструкция "прилагательное с зависимыми словами вообще возможна).

Далее, формулировка "переход причастия в прилагательное" как минимум дискуссионна. Вряд ли сам такой переход возможен, куда как правильнее было бы сказать, что наличие зависимых слов позволяет считать слово причастием, то есть это не законодательное правило, а всего лишь признак грамматической роли. Получше звучат формулировки типа "при наличии зависимых слов прилагательное ***заменяется*** на аналогичное причастие", хотя и это уже не совсем верно, но по крайней мере не несет внутренней путаницы.

Вообще этот случай надо бы разбирать в рамках более общей ситуации, связанной с неоднозначностью подхода к систематике и терминологии, когда в результате определение )то есть закон!) смешивается с признаком (следствием), но это была бы совершенно неподъёмная работа в рамках ресурса.

Постараюсь лишь очень бегло обрисовать ситуацию с отглагольными прилагательными и причастиями.

Во-первых, само их существование как разных частей речи (то есть с возможностью уверенного дифференцирования) не является общепризнанным. Предельно четко это сформулировал еще в семидесятые годы Аванесов. Он рассматривал конструкцию типа "стриженые волосы" или "груженые повозки", последовательно наполнял её зависимыми словами (стриженые ежиком, стриженные ежиком в парикмахерской, стриженный ежиком парикмахером - и так далее до бесконечности) - и задавался риторическим вопросом, где в этом ряду кончается прилагательное и начинается причастие.

Во-вторых. Такое впечатление (и ваш вопрос тому подтверждение), что некоторые носители языка, да и серьезные авторы подчас, весь смысл разделения причастий и прилагательных видят в создании для них разной орфографии. В то время как ситуация прямо противоположная. Не будь у причастий и прилагательных внутренних смысловых и отчасти - грамматических различий, различия в орфографии не продержались бы и нескольких лет. Суть-то в том, что, как вам, конечно, известно, причастия и прилагательные характеризуют объект с разных сторон. Причастия - как состояние, а прилагательные - как качество.

Этим и объясняется, что причастия и отглагольные прилагательные рассматриваются как  разные (или условно-разные) части речи и имеют разную орфорграфию.
Разговоры о переходе одного в другое в контексте орфографии просто неправомерны.  В отношении, например, зависимых слов дело обстоит так, что зависимые слов почти всегда (но тоже с оговоркой "почти") есть именно у причастий. Но их наличие - не определение, не законодательное правило, а лишь формальный признак, индикатор, к тому же - не абсолютный. Попытки доопределить грамматику через положения типа "причастие это то, что имеет зависимые слова" ни к чему хорошему не приводят, только смешивают причину и следствие.

И возвращаясь к орфографии. Можно с некоторой уверенностью сказать, что различия в орфографии при всей своей формальности позволяют (при некотором "вполне "школьном" навыке использования) лучше передать смысл написанного. Иначе эти различия были бы бесполезны и изжили бы себя очень быстро.

> Почему они влияют на написание НЕ именно с причастиями, но не с
>   прилагательными?

Это не совсем так, но как раз более или менее понятно. Здесь проявляется глагольная составляющая причастия. "Не с глаголами пишется раздельно". Если проанализировать все правила написания не с причастиями, не имеющие аналогов для прилагательных, то понятно, что все они так или иначе связаны со свойствами, более присущими глаголам, а не прилагательным.

Подробности этого пока опускаю. Можно бы отдельным вопросом, если потребуется.

---

(+) Я не читал другие ответы. Писал полностью от себя. Сейчас посмотрел - даже комментировать не хочется. Вообще не понимаю, о чем там речь. Ясно, что вопрос мы поняли по-разному.
А знаете, в чем дело? Причинно-следственной связи на самом деле просто нет. А если есть, то все её понимают по-разному.

Мораль, о которой я уже говорил не раз. Никогда не начинайте свой вопрос с "почему", если хотите получить простой, внятный и при этом правильный ответ.
Вопросы с"почему" обычно имеют только один общепринятый ответ. "Потому что гладиолус".

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.  Я согласна с вашим утверждением, что наличие зависимых слов позволяет считать слово причастием, что это  всего лишь признак грамматической роли и что нет перехода прилагательного в причастие  (или наоборот) в том смысле, как это обычно понимается. Я читала книгу Лопатина на эту тему -  «Русское правописание сегодня» (2007 год), но  я категорически не согласна с его мнением.

Comment: В частности, он предлагает изменить формулировку правила о зависимых словах. Он считает, что выбор Н/НН нужно связать с наличием зависимых слов чисто формально, не определяя грамматику отглагольной формы (причастие это или прилагательное), не проводя вообще никакого анализа, просто сохранить имеющуюся традицию письма.  Он полагает, что такое упрощение будет полезным. Но такой подход ведет к окончательной формализации правил, которые нужно будет только учить, но не понимать.

Answer (score 0):

*Крашенный* - это страдательное причастие от красить, а не "переход прилагательного в причастие".

А *крашеный* - это отдельное отглагольное прилагательное, с синхронной точки зрения словообразовательно мотивированное напрямую глаголом красить.

И это тоже признак по действию, только без вида, времени, залога и управления.

---

У Пешковского я читал, что многие отглагольные прилагательные на -ен (сушёный, мочёный) исторически были причастиями, но со временем перешли в прилагательные. А с точки зрения синхронии (формальной и семантической мотивации в современном языке) - это не отпричастные прилагательные, а "сразу прилагательные", образованные от основы глагола суффиксацией, *т. е. крас-и-ть --- краш-ен-ый*. Формант - суффикс -ен.

А в качестве причастий сегодня используются, соответственно, сушенный и моченный с двумя -нн.

---

А современные причастия, переходящие в прилагательные, сохраняют две -нн- в своём суффиксе.

1. Я оживил труп (оживлённый мною труп) - прич.
2. Оживл**ённ**ое движение (с двумя нн, а не о*живл**ён**ое* движение, с одной) - прил.

*Оживлённый* перешёл в прилагательное ведь не только не из-за отсутствия зависимых слов, но и оттого, что семантически он стал осознаваться как прилагательное, близкое по значению прилагательным "живой", "активный".

---

Вообще, например, *субъект действия* в творительном падеже оттеняет "причастность, глагольность" формы:

- "Оживлённая (мною) улица". - причастие.

Место действия тоже оттеняет "причастность, глагольность" формы:

- "Оживлённая (вчера) улица". - причастие.

---

А при отсутствии обстоятельственных признаков (места, времени, субъекта, причины, цели, уступки) форма ближе к прилагательному:

- "Оживлённая" (живая, кипящая) улица. - прилагательное

Даже мера и степень не оттеняет "причастность", потому что мера и степень - это признак, характерный и для прилагательного. Т. е:

- Очень (сильно, невероятно) живая улица.
- Очень (сильно, невероятно) оживлённая улица - не причастие, а прилагательное

---

Кстати, с синхронной точки зрения и такие формы (оживлённый, упрощённый) - это отглагольные прилагательные, потому что адъективация - не способ синхронного словообразования. Поэтому "диахронически отпричастные прилагательные" в синхронном словообразовании тоже считаются отглагольными прилагательными, и пара строится так: оживи-ть -- оживл-ённый, где -ённ - это деривационный аффикс отглагольного прилагательного.

Answer (score 0):

Коротко и просто вряд ли получится. Иначе вопроса бы, вероятно, и не было. Но можно коротко и ясно проанализировать примеры и сделать некоторые выводы.

*Ещё непроверенный текст — текст ещё [до сих пор] [остаётся] непроверенный.*
При раздельном написании после частицы подразумевается слово "был":
*Ещё не [был] проверенный текст.* || Раздельное написание подчёркивает отсутствие действия.

*Незамерзающая река* — постоянный признак.
*Не замерзающая зимой река.* || "Не замерзает зимой" лучше, чем "текущая/жидкая зимой река".
Качество усиливается в конечной позиции:
*Эта река зимой (какая?) незамерзающая.*

1) Очень помогают вопросы *каков? какова?*, указывающие не качество:
*Какова эта река? — Она незамерзающая.* || Нормально.
*Какова эта река? — Не замерзающая зимой.* || Зависимое слово как бы рушит ответ на вопрос о признаке, так как это не качество на данный момент, а отсутствие процесса (действия) замерзания именно в зимний период.

Анализ примеров Розенталя:

*Не [были] замеченные корректором опечатки* — именно зависимое слово делает акцент в сторону действия:
*Какие эти опечатки? — Незамеченные.* || Нормально.
*Какие эти опечатки? — Не замеченные корректором.* || С зависимым словом это не признак, а отрицание действия.

При зависимых словах, указывающих на время, качественный признак может преобладать:
*веками нетронутая земля* — веками земля была нетронутая.
Но при воздействии конкретного существительного, указывающего на определённое событие, действие выходит на первый план:
*рябина, не [была] тронутая осенними заморозками*.

2) Именно глагол "быть" может помочь обнаружить причастие.

*По независящим от редакции обстоятельствам* — слово "быть" никак не подставить после "не".
*Рефлексы, не зависящие от воли человека* — по аналогии с "рефлексы, которые не зависят".

Ещё играют роль предлоги:
***Для*** южных культур условия (какие?) неподходящие. || Предлог характерен для качества: *для кого-то условия такие-то*.
*Написания, не подходящие [не подходят] **под** правило.* || Предлог характерен для действия: *написания такие-то под правило* — полная ерунда.

3) Да и вообще, такая **замена слитного причастия местоимением** (*такой*) больше всего помогает. Думаю, что это **лучший способ**. Даже можно и не искать синонимы.

4) Ключевое здесь то, что синоним нужно подбирать только к причастию, не включая зависимое слово:
*ненадкушенное яблоко — целое яблоко*. || Отлично.
Но: *целое человеком яблоко*. || Ерунда, не подходит. Именно зависимое слово указывает на действие: *яблоко не было надкушено человеком*.
*Немытая посуда* — грязная посуда. || Отлично.
*Грязная человеком посуда.* || Не подходит. Творительный падеж больше всего указывает на действие.

---

*Крашенные в разный цвет волосы.* — заменим местоимением: *такие-то в разный цвет волосы*. || Нет, качество здесь не получается. Зависимые слова "ломают" его. Но с "*явно такие (крашеные) волосы*" всё отлично.

---

И теперь вывод: со многими зависимыми словами использование прилагательных невозможно, зато возможно — глаголов (и соответственно, причастий).

---

> Почему они [зависимые слова] влияют на написание НЕ именно с причастиями, но не с прилагательными?

Да как бы на прилагательные тоже влияют:
http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=77 (пункт 8)

Answer (score 0):

Вместо комментария к ответу oleedd

Нарисованная вами картинка мне показалась неясной, вероятно, она неясная и у многих других пользователей языка. Кто в этом виноват и что делать?

Отчасти виноваты **формальные** правила, которые пишутся в виде пошаговых инструкций. Виноваты **неточные формулировки терминов** из области грамматики.

Да, прилагательные вида *крашеный, стриженый* при наличии зависимых слов **не переходят в причастия.**

В языке существуют разные классы слов, образованных от глаголов: отглагольные прилагательные и причастия. И при наличии зависимых слов мы используем глагольную форму из класса причастий, а при их отсутствии нас вполне устроит отглагольное прилагательное. **Такой выбор мы делаем согласно правилам.** Также мы помним о том, что причастие – это форма глагола, а зависимые слова в причастном обороте берутся из глагольного сочетания.

**Но почему действует это правило, ведь зависимые слова бывают разные.** Если они обозначают производителя действия или время/место действия, то это вполне логично. А если они обозначают признак признака, а не действия, тогда как? ( Это как раз тот пример: *стриженые волосы – стриженные ежиком волосы*).

А тогда для простоты такие примеры отдельно не рассматриваются (слишком много мы хотим от орфографии). **Все зависимые слова считаются одинаковыми и не дифференцируются по значению.** Есть зависимое слово (любое) – значит, надо использовать причастие, а не прилагательное.

Правда, есть **исключение**, а именно отпричастные прилагательные, полученные переходом причастия в прилагательное (адъективация причастия).

Вот парный пример:

*Каждое не сдержанное вами слово подрывает доверие к вам* (причастие).   *Мне не нравятся несдержанные в проявлении своих чувств люди* (отпричастное прилагательное).

Несдержанные люди – это вспыльчивые люди (то есть возможна замена синонимом), но обратим внимание! Прямая подстановка синонима в предложение  может быть некорректной: *Мне не нравятся вспыльчивые  в проявлении своих чувств люди* (так не говорят).
Это как раз к предыдущей теме о несогласованных с заказчиком /незапланированных  сплит-системах.

**С раздельным написанием НЕ при наличии зависимых слов примерно та же история**. Хотя одиночные причастия прилагательными не называются, но они близки к ним по значению, так как  могут обозначать качественный признак: *непросохшая (влажная) одежда* (ведь время, место и производитель действия не указаны).

Но если есть зависимые слова (они взяты из глагольного сочетания с раздельным написанием НЕ), то **раздельное написание НЕ с причастием сохраняется**: *Река не замерзает зимой – не замерзающая зимой река.*

Comment: Очень важный момент. Замена не должна стилистически звучать. А быть верной грамматически. При замене (про вспыльчивость) смысл улавливается. Вот, про "глагольное сочетание" я и рассказывал в ответе, просто вы дали этому название. Но его нужно как-то определить. Или синонимом, что часто затруднительно, или местоимением (мне очень помогает): *Мне не нравятся вот такие в проявлении своих чувств люди.* Мы не оцениваем стилистику — местоимение примерно подставляется. Но творительный падеж с предлогом "с" указывает на действие: *установка таких-то с заказчиком систем*. Сюда не подставляется.